# Want to display only first class in the <div> using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi i want to display only **first div test** inside the class **ProductPriceRating** and i want to hide rest of the div's. Can anybdy help me.

```html
<div class="ProductPriceRating">
            <strong>$47.00</strong>
            
            <div class="test"><input type="button" class="btn" id="hello_123" onclick="window.open('1234')" value="test.com">
            <div class="test"><input type="button" class="btn" id="hello_123" onclick="window.open('1234')" value="test.com"></div>
            <div class="test"><input type="button" class="btn" id="hello_123" onclick="window.open('1234')" value="test.com"></div>
            <div class="test"><input type="button" class="btn" id="hello_123" onclick="window.open('1234')" value="test.com"></div>
            <div class="test"><input type="button" class="btn" id="hello_123" onclick="window.open('1234')" value="test.com"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What have you tried, should be as easy as `$('.ProductPriceRating .test').not(':first').hide();`

Comment: `$('.btn').not(':first').hide()`

Answer (score 2):

You miss `</div>` for first `.test` And your code will be

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.ProductPriceRating .test:first-of-type').addClass('active');
})
```

```css
.test {
  display: none;
}
.test.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ProductPriceRating">
  <strong>$47.00</strong>

  <div class="test">
    <input type="button" class="btn" id="hello_123" onclick="window.open('1234')" value="test.com">
  </div>
  <div class="test">
    <input type="button" class="btn" id="hello_123" onclick="window.open('1234')" value="test.com1">
  </div>
  <div class="test">
    <input type="button" class="btn" id="hello_123" onclick="window.open('1234')" value="test.com">
  </div>
  <div class="test">
    <input type="button" class="btn" id="hello_123" onclick="window.open('1234')" value="test.com">
  </div>
  <div class="test">
    <input type="button" class="btn" id="hello_123" onclick="window.open('1234')" value="test.com">
  </div>
</div>
```

Don't use same ID more than once per page!

Answer (score 2):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .test{display:none;}
    .test:nth-child(2) {
       display: block !important;
     }
</style>
 </head>
 <body>
<div class="ProductPriceRating">
        <strong>$47.00</strong>

        <div class="test"><input type="button" class="btn" id="hello_123" onclick="window.open('1234')" value="test.com"></div>
        <div class="test"><input type="button" class="btn" id="hello_123" onclick="window.open('1234')" value="test.com"></div>
        <div class="test"><input type="button" class="btn" id="hello_123" onclick="window.open('1234')" value="test.com"></div>
        <div class="test"><input type="button" class="btn" id="hello_123" onclick="window.open('1234')" value="test.com"></div>
        <div class="test"><input type="button" class="btn" id="hello_123" onclick="window.open('1234')" value="test.com"></div>
```

Comment: No  Need to use any funky library it can be achievable please use this

Comment: Topic starter asked in jquery:-)

Comment: As i can see he did not mentioned the name of jquery.. :) he just want to achieve something which can be easily achievable through css why to add a big lib to achieve that